# $3(2x+d)+c(x+5)=10x+17$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algebraic-equations

Given "$3(2x+d)+c(x+5)=10x+17$" what are the values of c and d. Upon expansion we get $6x+3d+cx+5c=10x+17$, meaning c must be equal to 4.

I was playing around with the equation and I found something I can't quite understand.

$$6x+3d+cx+5c=10x+17,$$

$$6x+cx=10x+17-3d-5c,$$

$$cx-4x=17-3d-5c$$

$$x=\frac{17-3d-5c}{c-4}$$

Previously I found $c$ to be $4$, but plugging in the value of c into the above, gives the denominator a value of zero, which is undefined upon division. What does this mean? Does a real value of x not exist or is x undefined. Could someone please help me to understand what is going on?

Comment: If you set $c = 4$, wouldn't the $x$ terms disappear and then you have $0 = -3 - 3d$?  Thus forcing you to set $d = -1$ to have the equation make sense?

Comment: The original equation is equivalent to asking what constants $c,d$ give me the same straight line $10x+17$. Then what you've done is to ask "what is the point of intersection of 2 straight lines?". Since you deal with the same straight line, the answer is infinitely many. Check the quotient you got by plugging $c=4,d=-1$ and you see $\frac{0}{0}$ form.

Answer (score 1):

If you sub $c=4$ into the expanded equation you can quickly find that $d=-1$. If you sub both these values into your final expression for $x$ you get $x=\frac{0}{0}$. In other words $x$ could be anything.

The problem is that you are in effect trying to find $x$ by solving the equation $10x+17=10x+17$ which of course cannot give you a specific result because it is true for all $x$

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a more general remark: Your eqution has three unknowns ($c$, $d$, and $x$), so you have to specify what you want to solve for.

The naming of the unknown suggests that you consider the left and right-hand side of your equation as functions of $x$, where the left hand-side depends on two parameters $c$ and $d$, and you want them to be equal. Thus, you're not lookign for a specific value of $x$ such that the equation holds, but you want it to be true **for all $x$.**

Thus, once you can calculate the parameters  as in robert's answer, the two sides are identical (by construction), and you cannot also fix a value of $x$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: In other words is the above an identity rather than an equation?

Comment: @DominicTorreto That depends a bit on your nomenclature, but I guess that, yes, it's supposed to be an identity in the sense of "equality of functions" rather than equality of numbers.